# How do I (properly) render at a high frame rate in pure Java

Tags: java, swing

I've been trying to make a simple game in pure java and I've encountered a problem in drawing. I'm trying to keep a relatively high frame-rate but having issues with the fact that JFrame.repaint() cannot be 'forced' and is merely a request to have the frame redrawn at the next available opportunity. As a result, the below code's frame-rate is terrible. However, (and this is the strange part) it seems to only be terrible when my mouse isn't moving. If my mouse is moving and over-top of the window, the frame rate is fast and crisp.

I've tried various online suggestions and even compiled examples on how to do this and they all seem to have the same issue with the frame rate dropping dramatically when my mouse isn't moving over the window.

(I'm using Linux, if that matters)

Any and all help is much appreciated!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Test extends JPanel {


  public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new Test());


    for (int k = 0; k < 1_000_000; k++) {
      frame.repaint();
      try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
      }
    }

    frame.dispose();
    System.exit(0);
  }



  private int k = 0;

  public Test() {
    super();
  }

  @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    int height = (int) (((k * 0.01) % 1) * getHeight());
    g.drawLine(
      0, height,
      getWidth(), height
      );

    k++;

  }

}
```

Comment: Better have a look at gamedev.stackexchange.com. This looks like a useful question for you ("don't update your "k" in the paint method, base it on the wall clock") https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/43347/how-to-handle-frame-rates-and-synchronizing-screen-repaints

Comment: `it seems to only be terrible when my mouse isn't moving. If my mouse is moving and over-top of the window, the frame rate is fast and crisp.` - frame rate seems the same to me whether the mouse is moving or not. I'm using JDK8 on Window 7. Also, just set the background of the panel in the constructor. No need to paint the background twice.

Comment: Well just put the K in there for simplicity's sake. the game is much more complicated. I just wrote a quick little bit of code to demonstrate my problem with the rendering updates. But I'll take a look at gamedev. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if it could be a OS specific issue, because I noticed that online examples (presumably which worked fine for those who wrote them) were doing something similar. I'm using JDK8 on Kbuntu 17.04

Comment: If you want complete control over the painting process, you should consider having a look at `BufferStrategy`, which is the closest Java will allow you to get to the hard ware using pure Java - you'd have to resort to 3rd party libraries to (arguably) do better

Comment: You should also implement logic which deducts the amount of time it took to  update and render the backing buffer from the amount of time you need to wait in order to present a constant frame rate. So if you're targeting 60fps, you'd need to wait a total of 16 milliseconds. If the update process takes 6 milliseconds, you'd only have to wait 10 milliseconds

Comment: Also, make sure that the "update process" is separated from the "paint process", they shouldn't rely on the same data, so you'd need some kind of page swapping buffer in place, so when the "main loop" is updating the buffer, it's not updating to the same buffer which is been painted

Comment: You must not modify the state of anything in a paint method, because that method can be called for many reasons besides your explicit calls to `repaint`.  In fact, it’s possible for a single `repaint` to trigger multiple calls to a paint method, or zero calls.  Also, your loop belongs inside your try/catch, not the other way around;  it impacts performance, and an interrupt is an explicit request for your thread to stop what it’s doing and exit gracefully.

Comment: I'm perfectly aware that the code is less than perfect. I wrote it quickly to demonstrate a problem which I had encountered with code which is valid in the respects which have thus far been pointed out. Changing the increment of k has no effect, nor does optimizing performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After far too much research, it turns out that java does not sync / flush the display buffer automatically on many Linux systems. All the repaints and such were correct, however the display buffer was not flushing, thus creating the strange lagging effect.

The Solution:

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); /* get AWT toolkit */

/* initialize things */
...

while (your_loop) {

  /* run your logic */
  ...

  /* paint everything */
  ...

  toolkit.sync(); /* force display buffer to flush */
}
```

Thank you all for your input

Answer (score 1):

The question is not simple. The code below has not been tested, then just to give you the idea... In the next lines, AWT is the underlying of Swing.

First, you have to keep your `paintComponent()` very fast (indeed!). This is the first requirement. Basically, for 60 fps, you must draw in less than 15 milliseconds. Forget transaparency and other stuff (works badly on Windows, I don't know for Linux). Try to save calculations when possible.

Second, Execute everything else in a different thread. This is the way I use for my own program. Note every call to AWT (included Swing, of course) must be encapsulated in a call to [EventQueue.invokeLater()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) to ensure you are running stuff in the AWT thread because setting a label MUST NOT be done outside the AWT thread.

Do not forget to create a thread when you receive an input from AWT that takes time!

Third, replace your loop by a [timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) like

```
new Timer("Drawer", true).scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTak(){
    public void run(){
       frame.repaint();
    }
}, 
100, // Start in 100 ms
(int)(1000 / 60)); // 60 is the frame rate.
```

Everything should work smoothly. For the frame count `k`, use the following:

```
// You should initialize just before you create the timer...!
static private long startedAt = System.currentTimeMillis();

@Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // Microseconds since the game started.
    long k = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startedAt);

    // Increment only one by frame (60 fps)
    k = (int)((double)k * 60 / 1000.0)

    // Draw the game...!      
}
```

That's all. Note some frames can be dropped if the computer is not enough powerful (or CPU intensive is required, or garbage collector...). But, when possible, your game will run at a maximum of 60 fps.

*Bonus:* if you increment a value each time you go through the `paintComponent()`, you can find the number of frames dropped or the average number of frames per second really displayed since the start of the game.

Comment: Unfortunately this (while slightly better) still has the same issue