# Java Swing Paint Performance

Tags: java, swing, paint, frame-rate, paintcomponent

I'm developing a game using Java Swing and because of high responsive notion of the game, it has to have a high FPS. Yet after optimizing my program in any way I knew, it still takes a lot of time to simply paint images on the JPanel. (about 20ms per each entity) Here's my custom paint method in paintComponent:

```
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (GeoShapeView shapeView: shapeViews) {
            Point location = getRelativeLocation(getCornerAnchorLocation(shapeView.getViewId()));
            shapeView.rotatedIcon.paintIcon(this, g, location.x, location.y);
        }
    }
```

where rotatedIcon is a class implementing Icon:

```
package view;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

import static view.Utils.rotatedInfo;

public class RotatedIcon implements Icon {

    private final Icon icon;

    @SuppressWarnings("FieldMayBeFinal")
    private Point rotationAnchor;
    private double degrees;
    private final boolean isCircular;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    public RotatedIcon(BufferedImage image, Point rotationAnchor, double degrees, boolean isCircular) {
        this.icon=new ImageIcon(image);
        this.rotationAnchor=rotationAnchor;
        this.degrees=degrees;
        this.isCircular = isCircular;
    }
    @Override
    public int getIconWidth() {
        if (isCircular) return icon.getIconWidth();
        else return width;
    }
    @Override
    public int getIconHeight() {
        if (isCircular) return icon.getIconHeight();
        else return height;
    }
    @Override
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        Dimension viewSizeSave=new Dimension(icon.getIconWidth(),icon.getIconHeight());
        Point[] rotatedInfo= rotatedInfo(viewSizeSave,rotationAnchor,degrees,isCircular);
        width=rotatedInfo[0].x;
        height=rotatedInfo[0].y;

        int lowerX=Math.max(x-rotatedInfo[1].x,0);
        int lowerY=Math.max(y-rotatedInfo[1].y,0);
        int upperX=Math.min(lowerX+getIconWidth(),c.getWidth());
        int upperY=Math.min(lowerY+getIconHeight(),c.getHeight());
        
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setClip(lowerX,lowerY, upperX-lowerX, upperY-lowerY);
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees), x+rotationAnchor.x,y+rotationAnchor.y);
        icon.paintIcon(c, g2d, x, y);
        g2d.dispose();
    }
```

Finally, I don't think it might be of importance but here's the rotatedInfo method:

```
    public static Point[] rotatedInfo(Dimension viewSize,Point relativeAnchor,double angle,boolean isCircular){
        //Returns an array of 2 points containing newSize, Offset

        if (isCircular) return new Point[]{new Point(viewSize.width,viewSize.height),new Point(0,0)};
        Point[] corners=new Point[]{new Point(0,0),new Point(viewSize.width,0),new Point(0,viewSize.height),new Point(viewSize.width,viewSize.height)};
        Point[] rotatedCorners=new Point[4];
        for (int i=0;i<corners.length;i++) rotatedCorners[i]=rotateAbout(relativeAnchor,corners[i],angle);
        ArrayList<Integer> rotatedCornersX=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> rotatedCornersY=new ArrayList<>();
        for (Point point: rotatedCorners){
            rotatedCornersX.add(point.x);
            rotatedCornersY.add(point.y);
        }
        int xLower= Collections.min(rotatedCornersX);
        int yLower= Collections.min(rotatedCornersY);
        int xUpper= Collections.max(rotatedCornersX);
        int yUpper= Collections.max(rotatedCornersY);

        return new Point[]{new Point(xUpper-xLower,yUpper-yLower),new Point(-xLower,-yLower)};
    }
```

I did everything I knew and noticed to speed up the custom painting but as I mentioned, it's still too slow.

I tried using a SwingWorker to do the computations of the graphics in another thread but it turned out to take twice the time it currently takes to paint entities.
I'm pretty sure the thing causing to the low speed of painting is in the code snippets I included.
Any help/clue/reference would be much appreciated.

Comment: 1) Post an [mre] demonstrating the problem. 2) Not really sure what your RotatedIcon class is doing but here is my version of a [Rotated Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/).

Comment: You seem to be doing a lot of calculations while you're painting.  Swing painting should just paint.  Minimal calculations.  Your major calculations should be happening elsewhere in the code, leaving the `paintComponent` method to paint the status of the logical model.

Comment: @camickr all it does is that it gets the angle of rotation and location and draws the rotated icon. I also did take a look on your link and it didn't seem to have anything more "efficient". Mine is just doing less things

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I (properly) render at a high frame rate in pure Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46626715/how-do-i-properly-render-at-a-high-frame-rate-in-pure-java)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I don't think I can provide the change I made to my code in this post (since I moved these methods to other classes irrelevant to the problem context) but now I'm at about 0.3 ms per entity (yet I don't know if this is considered optimal as a general swing performance) Thanks a lot! I don't know why I just undertake the magnitude of effect computing in EDT has on Swing performance everytime until someone reminds it to me :)

Comment: I kind of agree with Camickr, your `RotatedIcon` should be doing nothing more than rendering the result of the calculation.  You could set the calculation in a seperate thread and the apply the result back to the `RotatedIcon` in som way.  But, you code is missing the `rotateAbout` method so I can't even run it.  If you need higher FPS, you should consider making use of `BufferedStrategy`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the response! I changed the code due to Gilbert's comment and now the only think that is taking any time is the lines related to the paint process itself and there is no calculation in between to be done in a separate thread. And yes, because my code is a bit large-scaled, I thought it would be best if I just put the parts relative to the paint method in this post. Also, I'd be thankful if you could tell me how BufferedStrategy is going to help getting higher FPS

Comment: @Aryan BufferStategy takes you out of the Swing paint process and gives you complete control over the rendering process - so essentially, as fast as you can render images

Comment: When using Swing painting in a Swing `Timer` game loop, the minimum time I've found for a stable Swing `Timer` is 5 ms, or 200 frames/second.  I've found anything shorter to be unstable.  Most Swing animation looks good at 33 frames/second, or 30 ms per frame.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc A pretty unrelated question. Doesn't the very notion of Swing Timers interfere with high responsiveness of GUI? (because of the time drift) This question randomly came up since I regulated the FPS only by replacing my Timers with a GameLoop

Comment: As I said in my comment, 33 frames/second is good enough for most animations.  What do you gain by updating the display faster?  If you mean the responsiveness of the GUI to user input, keep long operations off the Event Dispatch Thread.  30 ms response time is pretty good.